# Change the color of a pixel in an imagesc plot without repainting everything in Matlab/Octave

Tags: matlab, octave

I have a for-loop where I would like to paint at every step a new pixel in an imagesc plot. I am currently repainting the whole figure but the figure is blinkering and I know it is not the proper way to do so. Can anyone help to find the appropriate function to do this task?

Comment: How large is the image you're trying to display? Would it be possible to update less frequently?

Comment: The image is 200 * 200, I really would like to update it at each step because I would like to follow the evolution precisely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can address the data in each pixel with the `CData` property of the image without having to close and redraw the figure, axes, or axes object over and over.  Ends up being about 1.5x - 2x faster than trying to generate a new image object or just calling `imagesc()` over and over.

In these loops don't forget the `drawnow` call or MATLAB will try to skip the figure drawing until the looping completes.

Example code:

```
data = rand(200, 200); % Data to display

figure(1) % Make a figure
imgHand = imagesc(data); % Display data in it

% Naive way - call imagesc() each time.
% Slow.  Don't do it this way.
for k = 1:numel(data);

    data(k) = data(k) + 10*rand(1,1); % Update data
    imagesc(data) % Redraw it by calling imagesc()

    drawnow; % Display updated figure

end

% Faster way - address CData of image object directly
% 1.5-2x faster than above method
for k = 1:numel(data);

    data(k) = data(k) + 10*rand(1,1); % Update data
    set(imgHand, 'CData', data); % Change CData property of object

    drawnow; % Display updated figure

end
```

Comment: ah I always forget about `cdata`.  Very nice. +1

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a choice but to paint everything at each iteration if you want to draw **every** frame that has an update.  However, you can **minimize** the flickering (or perhaps even remove it) by perhaps placing a `pause` at the end of your loop before the next iteration.  This way, it'll give the frame buffer a chance to draw to the screen completely before you draw the next frame.

Something like:

```
for idx = 1 : total_frames
    %// Do stuff

    drawnow; %// Draw frame
    pause(0.1); %// Pause
end
```

`total_frames` would be the total number of times you are refreshing the plot, and inside the loop you would do the work necessary, you then draw the figure, then pause for 0.1 ms.  Adjust the time to whatever works for you.